# Mapbox JS layers code displays blank page

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to create a map of historic violence in the US with multiple layers of data to turn on and off. I have seven different tilesets in different layers. I tried modifying the example on the mapbox documentation but all I get is a short grey line. I'm a Mapbox newbie and a History teacher, not a professional coder. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Museum of Intolerance</title>    
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

</head>
<body>  
 
<nav id="menu"></nav>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'TOKEN';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/STYLE', // stylesheet location
    zoom: 3 // starting zoom
    center: [-95, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
});
map.on('load', function() {
// add source and layer for WaPo
map.addSource('WaPo', {
    type: 'vector',
    url: 'mapbox://jmcdonaldgcs.a9zkf6ur'
});
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'WaPo',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'WaPo',
    'layout': {
// make layer visible by default
    'visibility': 'visible'
},
'paint': {
    'circle-radius': 2,
    'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
},
    'source-layer': 'WaPo'
});
 
        
// enumerate ids of the layers
var toggleableLayerIds = ['WaPo'];

 
// set up the corresponding toggle button for each layer
for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];
 
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = '#';
link.className = 'active';
link.textContent = id;
 
link.onclick = function(e) {
var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
 
var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');
 
// toggle layer visibility by changing the layout object's visibility property
if (visibility === 'visible') {
map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
this.className = '';
} else {
this.className = 'active';
map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
}
};
 
var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
layers.appendChild(link);
}   
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: G'day and welcome. Suggest you have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help on how to make a minimal example that people can use to help you.

Comment: Thanks. In my first question, I was told I didn't post enough code. In testing, I don't get any indication of where the error is. In Drupal and other projects I've worked on, I get a line error to tell me where the problem fails. Here it's just a blank page. So I dunno where to cut down to post. I did read the link you sent me, but I'm not sure where to start with my particular example.

Comment: Well, for starters, you're adding a lot of layers there. You only need to add one to get started, right? Find the smallest measure of success (a map with a single layer) and remove everything that is not relevant to that.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I did that.

Comment: Now go through and remove all the CSS that is not relevant here. We're really going for *minimal*.

Comment: Okay thanks. I did that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your code had several syntax errors (comma after zoom on map creation and close of the scope of map on load), and it was missing the styles for the map to position properly. This code works at least to paint the map, but I'm not able to download the json file `mapbox://jmcdonaldgcs.a9zkf6ur`, if you share it I could help with the rest of the functionality.

Regards!

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Museum of Intolerance</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.11.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='map' class='map'>
</div>

<script>

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'PUT HERE YOUR TOKEN';

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
        zoom: 3, // starting zoom
        center: [-95, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    });
    map.on('load', function () {
        // add source and layer for WaPo
        map.addSource('WaPo', {
            type: 'vector',
            url: 'mapbox://jmcdonaldgcs.a9zkf6ur'
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'WaPo',
            'type': 'circle',
            'source': 'WaPo',
            'layout': {
                // make layer visible by default
                'visibility': 'visible'
            },
            'paint': {
                'circle-radius': 2,
                'circle-color': 'rgba(55,148,179,1)'
            },
            'source-layer': 'WaPo'
        });


        // enumerate ids of the layers
        var toggleableLayerIds = ['WaPo'];


        // set up the corresponding toggle button for each layer
        for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
            var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = '#';
            link.className = 'active';
            link.textContent = id;

            link.onclick = function (e) {
                var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

                // toggle layer visibility by changing the layout object's visibility property
                if (visibility === 'visible') {
                    map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
                    this.className = '';
                } else {
                    this.className = 'active';
                    map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
                }
            };

            var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
            layers.appendChild(link);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Scotisle,Glad to help a History teacher! Please, vote the answer up if it solved your problem.
If you have any other issue once you read the json source, let me know